# How to shift all the value in an array down by one position and drop the last value in an array in Java?

Tags: java

Hi all Java professionals, 
I need one piece of guidance which is shifting all the value in an array down by one position and drop the last value in an array so that the new input is added into the beginning of the array in Java. The program keeps looping and the element keep shifting to the right.The following is my code, please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ass3a 
{ 
    public static void main(String []args) 
    { 
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
        double calculate [] = new double [10]; 
        double read; 
        String choice; 
        while (true) 
        { 
            System.out.println("\n the first index is "+calculate[0]); 
            System.out.println("1)Add \n2)Drop \n3)Stop:"); 
            choice=reader.nextLine(); 
            char choose =choice.charAt(0); 

            switch (choose) 
            { 
                case '1': 
                Add( calculate); 
                break; 
                default: System.out.println("No such an option."); 

            } 

        } 
    } 


    public static double Add (double calculate[]) 
    { 

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
        double replace=0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        { 
            if(calculate[i] == 0) 
            { 

                System.out.println("-----Adding-----"); 
                System.out.print("Please enter a number to add into the array:"); 
                calculate[i]=reader.nextDouble(); 
                System.out.println(calculate[i]); 
                replace = calculate[i]; 

                break; 

            } 

        } 

        return replace; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: So what behavior are you seeing out of the current code that is incorrect?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Are you dead set on arrays?  Seems like a list would be a better fit for that style of operation

Comment: you could use a queue data structure as well, with a push and pop call on it.

Comment: Can you give me a queue data example?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried few lines of code for you, it drops the last element in your array...

```
 public static double drop (double calculate[]) 
{ 
    double replace=0; 
    System.out.println("-----dropping-----"); 
    System.out.print("Please enter a number to add into the array:"); 
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    replace=reader.nextDouble();
    double temp;


    //calculate.length calculates the length of an array
     int len=calculate.length-1;



    //removing the last element of an array and shifting down the entire array 
    for(int i = 0; i <len; i++) 
    {   
    calculate[len-i]=calculate[len-(i+1)];
    }   
    calculate[0]=replace;

    System.out.println("Array now contains...");
    for(int j=0;j<calculate.length;j++)         
        System.out.println(calculate[j]);

    return replace; 
}
```

The demerit of using this method will be-- here the last element of the array is getting deleted on the last entered value. I have over come that by modifying your add method, Wherein the first element in stored in the last part of the array and now the code looks like this..

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class pg1 
    { 

    //Declared for easy access of arrays..
static int temp1;

    public static void main(String []args) 
    { 
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double calculate [] = new double [10];

    //Finding the length..  Have used a variable to increase the flexibility of the code. 
    //incase, if you want to change the array length at any point

    temp1=calculate.length-1;


    double read; 
    String choice; 
    while (true) 
    { 
        System.out.println("\n the first index is "+calculate[0]); 
        System.out.println("1)Add \n2)Drop \n3)Stop:"); 
        choice=reader.nextLine(); 
        char choose =choice.charAt(0); 

        switch (choose) 
        { 
            case '1': 
            Add( calculate); 
            break; 


            case '2':
            drop(calculate);
            break;

            default: System.out.println("No such an option.");
        } 

    } 
}
```

//This place is where major modifications have taken place

```
public static double Add (double calculate[]) 
{ 

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double replace=0; 

    //Only enters when the first element of the code is zero... Zero is the default value..
        if(calculate[0] == 0) 
        { 
            //Storing the elements into array and displaying it..

            System.out.println("-----Adding-----"); 
            System.out.print("Please enter a number to add into the array:"); 
            calculate[temp1--]=reader.nextDouble(); 



            System.out.println("Array now contains...");
            for(int j=0;j<calculate.length;j++)
                System.out.println(calculate[j]);
        }
        return replace;
}



public static double drop (double calculate[]) 
{ 
    double replace=0; 
    System.out.println("-----dropping-----"); 
    System.out.print("Please enter a number to add into the array:"); 
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    replace=reader.nextDouble();
    double temp;

    int len=calculate.length-1;

    for(int i = 0; i <len; i++) 
    {   
    calculate[len-i]=calculate[len-(i+1)];
    }   
    calculate[0]=replace;

    System.out.println("Array now contains...");
    for(int j=0;j<calculate.length;j++)         
        System.out.println(calculate[j]);

    return replace; 
}     
}
```

Happy Coding..